# How do you do the action for a form be null

Tags: javascript, html, forms

When defining a `<form>`, it is possible to set the `action` tag.

How can I set it to null (#), so that it will not actually change the page?

Comment: I cannot understand this question.

Comment: You're going to have to clarify this because currently it makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `<form>` tag without an `action` attribute will send the data to the page it was submitted from.

You only need to use the `action` attribute if you're sending the form data to a different page.

```
<form method="GET">
    <input type="text" size="10" name="input" value="default">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

(NOTE: This does not work on the `file:///` protocol handler.)

Answer (score 4):

A bit hard to understand but I think what you want is this:

```
<form action="#">
 <!-- code here -->
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else reading this, it is usually better to have your input or button object return false; when it's clicked. This will make sure the form doesn't follow an action, and instead stays on the page. It would be similar conceptually to what is being asked, as in it will stay on the current page.

This let's you handle submit options in javascript.

Here's an example of how you would submit an email address to your API route, alerting the user what is returned by the API call:

HTML:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="email">
<button onclick="do_something(); return false;"
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var do_something = function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://myapi.com/route",
    type: 'POST',
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    context: document.body
  }).done(function(data) {
    alert(data);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set form action to null in the following way. This worked for me.

```
< form action ='' >
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```html
<form method="dialog">
    <input type="text" size="10" name="input" value="default">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```